# Spring Security password encryption not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I had a security configuration which worked before I added a custom login filter. But now it stopped working. I am posting my security-context.xml below. i have tried giving all the three methods explained [here](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-password-hashing-example/). It was working fine before I added the custom filter. The custom filter dosn't do anything but add an extra field to the session to validate.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


    <beans:bean id="LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"> 
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/verify" /> 
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="subdomainFilter" class="com.testbudha.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilterWithSubdomain">
         <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="userAuthenticationManager"/>
    </beans:bean>
    <http pattern="/**" use-expressions='true' entry-point-ref="LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint" authentication-manager-ref="userAuthenticationManager">
        <custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="subdomainFilter" />        
        ........
    </http>


    <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"></beans:property>

    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <beans:property name="providers">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:ref local="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <!-- To prevent user from accessing secured website when back button is 
        pressed on browser -->
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
        <beans:property name="cacheSeconds" value="0" />
        <beans:property name="useExpiresHeader" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authSuccessHandler"
        class="com.testbudha.security.authentication.AuthRouterController" />
</beans:beans>
```

**Update** My code for saving the user

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signupnew",method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createNewUser(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
        String subdomain = extractSubDomain(request);
        UserInfo userInfo = getUserInfo(request);
        PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder(11);
        userInfo.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(userInfo.getPassword()));
        userInfo.setSubDomain_new(subdomain);
        if (getUserservice().saveUser_new(userInfo)) {
            TeamsLog log = new TeamsLog(userInfo.getUsername(), userInfo.getEmail());
            log.setMessage("User with email " + userInfo.getEmail() + " signed up.");
            log.setCreated(new Date());
            teamsLogger.log(log);
            model.addAttribute("message", ICommonMessage.SUCCESSFUL_USER_CREATION + userInfo.getEmail() + ". "
                    + ICommonMessage.SUCCESSFUL_USER_CREATION1);
        } else {
            model.addAttribute("errormessage", ICommonMessage.USER_CREATION_FAILURE_MESSAGE);
        }
        return "index";
    }
```

Comment: any exception? What do you see?

Comment: no exception. But when I run in debug mode I can see that the password coming from user is not encrypted

Comment: Did you store the password encrypted? or in clear text?

Comment: Encrypted using BCryptPasswordEncoder

Comment: your XMl is bit messed up, but it's okay for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would require that you post how you are saving the user code, then I will add modifications for that part as well. As for your XML, do this change, paste the encoder bean mentioned below in your XML and modify your authentication manager as posted below.

```
  <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </beans:bean>

 <authentication-manager alias="userAuthenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
            <security:password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Also, dont forget to put your registration code. Lemme know if there is a problem.
Also, I just saw that you are not providing reference for encoder in your daoAuthenticationProvider, there also you would require, something like this :

```
class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="LoginServiceImpl"/>
    <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="encoder"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: @Sumodhkrishna : The code is okay, but you have business logic in Controller, move it to Service layer. Secondly. you can also encrypt the password in one-line, without initialization like                 person.setPassword(BCrypt.hashpw(person.getPassword(), BCrypt.gensalt(11))); . Thirdly, you should modify your XML the way I suggested, this way the encoder bean will be injected in your dao, and you will be able to login. Also edit your main post to include your JSP/JSF/HTML code for login.

Comment: Thanks, I got it solved. As you suggested I moved my business logic to my service layer

Comment: I don't believe that was the only one thing, but good for you.